# doesnot use the provided mirror in settings.xml

Tags: maven, soapui

I need to download a dependency "proxy-vole" from maven and it is present on "https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public"

So I have mentioned the above url as mirror in my setting.xml in maven but everytime I run the project from maven ,it tries to download the jar file from other url (mirror 2) where this depency doesnot exists. and i get error.

my setting.xml is :

```
<mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>maven.alfresco</id>
            <mirrorOf>alfresco-public</mirrorOf>
            <name>alfresco artifacts repository</name>
            <url>https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        </mirror>
    <mirror>
            <id>FTRDProxy_central</id>
            <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
            <name>FTRD Maven Proxy mirroring central (maven 2) repository</name>
            <url>url for mirror2</url>
        </mirror>
        <mirror>
            <id>maven.apache</id>
            <mirrorOf>maven2</mirrorOf>
            <name>Apache Maven Proxy mirroring central (maven 2) repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        </mirror>
```

Comment: How is your "proxy-vole" dependency defined in POM?

Comment: as plugin dependency :-it is defined as plugin dependency as below:-<plugins>
  <plugin>
  <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
  <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>5.4.0</version>  
  <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                     <groupId>com.btr</groupId>
                    <artifactId>proxy-vole</artifactId>
                    <version>20121203</version>
                </dependency>